# How to "undo" a deleted element with splice?

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

When I have an array and I use `splice` to remove, let's say, the last element of the array. Is there a chance to create for example a button and when I click on it, it undoes the deleted action? Like using Ctrl + Z when write code and jump back in time? That means give me back the deleted element with all its characteristics?

Comment: The 'deleted' element has to come back in exactly the same position as before the deletion?

Comment: Yes, that is my plan.

Comment: why not to have an array of objects with one key to be "active" and instead of splicing, just set it false

Comment: @binariedMe This idea may be fine. Another question - does this array include duplicates?

Comment: Instead one can always go for saving the spliced elements in a trash array with its index, preserved. and thats how you can always undo it accordingly. Although you have to be careful with reinsertion of element in the original array.

Comment: @ Kind user, no duplicates. Is there a solution with duplicates ?

Comment: @DerickKolln Check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array.splice` allows you to delete or insert elements, it also returns the removed elements when deleting. If you capture the deleted elements you can easily add them back:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
// remove 1 element from index 1 ("2")
let removed = arr.splice(1, 1);
// add "2" back to position 1
arr.splice(1, 0, ...removed);

console.log(arr);
```

If you don't have access to ES6's spread operator, you could use `.shift()` to get the first element out of `removed`:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
// remove 1 element from index 1 ("2")
let removed = arr.splice(1, 1);
// add "2" back to position 1
arr.splice(1, 0, removed.shift());

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Hey, can you explain,what is the meaning of  the 3 dots `...` in the line `arr.splice(1, 0, ...removed);` ?

Comment: Sure, I'm using the [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to expand an array to it's values. In the code above `removed` is `[2]`, `...removed` gets expanded to `2`. If it were `[2, 3, 4]` then it would expand to `2, 3, 4`

Comment: Thanks. Could you maybe post the line `arr.splice(1, 0, ...removed)` without Spread Syntax? Would it be `arr = removed.splice(1, 0)?`

Comment: Updated my answer to include a method of achieving this without the spread syntax

Answer (score 2):

I'd be tempted to wrap your arrays in some kind of undoable utility. For example:

```
function undoable(value) {
  let history = [value];

  return {
    value() {
      return history[history.length - 1];
    },
    update(func) {
      let copy = [...this.value()];
      func(copy);
      history.push(copy);
      return copy;
    },
    undo() {
      history.pop();
      return this.value();
    }
  }
}
```

You could use this to handle undo behaviour.

```
let array = undoable([]);

array.update(arr => arr.push(2));
// [2]

array.update(arr => arr.push(3));
// [2, 3]

array.undo();
// [2]
```

You could make this even safer and more generic if you treat the values as immutable during the calls to `update`. At that point you wouldn't need to defensively copy your array before passing it to `func`. However, it would require you to use methods like `filter` and `slice` instead of `splice`.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need one level of undo, you can just copy the array before deletion.  If the user wants to "undo" then revert the array back to its previous incarnation.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var tempArr;

function removeThing(arr, index) {
   tempArr = arr;
   arr.splice(index, 1);
}

function undo() {
    arr = tempArr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on the `Delete random item` button will result in deletion of a random element from the `arr` array. The deleted element is being stored inside the `deleted` array.

Clicking on the `Undo deletion` button will move the deleted element back into the `arr` array, into the same position.

```js
var arr = [5,1,2,6,4,8,0,7],
    stored = arr.slice(),
    deleted = [],
    btn = document.getElementById('deleteBtn'),
    undoBtn = document.getElementById('undoBtn');
    
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
      var randomElem = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length),
          deleteElem = arr.splice(randomElem, 1);
          deleted.push(...deleteElem);
          console.log(arr);
          console.log(deleteElem);
    });
    
    undoBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
      if (arr.length >= 0 && arr.length < stored.length){
        var elem = deleted[deleted.length-1],
            index = stored.indexOf(elem);
            arr.splice(index, 0, elem);
            deleted.pop();
            console.log(arr);
      }
    });
    
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<button id='deleteBtn'>Delete random item</button>
<button id='undoBtn'>Undo deletion</button>
```